# How to upload demo image in my android github project

Tags: github

> I have uploaded my project to github account successfully but i am
>   able to add a demo image or gif to it.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to follow the suggestion at the bottom of your screenshot: Add a README

There you can embed images, both still or moving

Answer (score 0):

Click Add a README on your screen, or manually submit a file called README.md in the page that you want an image to be on *(You can have a different README.md file on every folder)*

In that file add a link to an image using this tag:

```
![screen shot](http://i.imgur.com/example.png)
```

Comment: hmm, that's not right, the picture should be equal to the size of the original pic, link me to your github page and I will update this answer according to your inputs.